# How to add rows to data frame of two lists

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I have two create a CSV for 2 lists. So I converted them to data frames and tried appending them but 2nd row keeps overwriting instead of adding it into a new row. The 'Time' keeps incrementing by 1. Can you please help me.

```
import pandas as pd
sensor_keys1 = open("sensor_keys1.csv", "w")
a = ['Time', 'sensor_Mtr_-12', 'sensor_Mtr_-12']
b= ['0', '1.2','1.3']
my_df1 = pd.DataFrame([a])
for i in range(0, 10):
    my_df2 =  pd.DataFrame([b])
    sensor_keys1=my_df1.append(my_df2)
    sensor_keys1.to_csv("new_sensor_keys1.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: please also add what sensor_keys1 looks like. Sample dataframes and sample output are required to really help you here

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to set the column names using the columns argument in `pd.DataFrame()`:

```
sensor_keys1 = open("sensor_keys1.csv", "w")
a = ['Time', 'sensor_Mtr_-12', 'sensor_Mtr_-12']
b= ['0', '1.2','1.3']

df = pandas.DataFrame([b], columns=a)
```

The `Time` incrementing by one indicates that it is set as index or you are confusing it with the index (cannot tell from your example as no sample output is given)

```
# append to the dataframe in the loop 
# (not most efficient way but can't tell from your example what you try to achieve)
for i in range(10):
    sensor_keys1 = sensor_keys1.append(df)

#save the df to csv file
sensor_keys1.to_csv("new_sensor_keys1.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: The desired output should be a csv(sensor_keys1.csv) which has list a as the headers and b as the rows. I get a new list everytime Time changes by 1

Comment: Time sensor_Mtr_-12 sensor_Mtr_-12
0     1.2         1.3
1     1.2         1.3